# Will it cause any issue to perform more than one page.evaluate in puppeteer for multiple DOM manipulation?

Tags: puppeteer

Currently, when I tried to perform two page.evaluate in puppeteer in order to execute two different kind of DOM manipulation, it just not really running the 2nd one at all.

Is there way I can run DOM manipulation in two different .evaluate or there is different way I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to make two `evaluate` calls? Why is it not enough to make one `evaluate` call with two functions (or Promises) inside?

Comment: @ThomasDondorf in another word, two evaluate do cause problem yes?

Comment: It should be perfectly fine. But if you share some part of your code, we might be able to see the actual reason of why 2nd one is not "really running".